Logstash jdbc input plugin fetches the data multiple times from the database which has no unique id or no timestamp
I created a pipeline called mypipeline and executed it in pipeline.yml (multipipeline) together with other pipelines.
The problem here is that I do not have neither any unique id or identifier column nor a timestamp which shows the modification date.
mypipeline.conf
input {
  jdbc {
    id => "database"
    jdbc_driver_library => "my_driver"
    jdbc_driver_class => "my_driver_class"
    jdbc_connection_string => "my_connection"
    jdbc_user => "db_user"
    jdbc_password => "db_password"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    statement_filepath => "mysql_query.sql"
  }
}

filter {
  mutate {
    id => "remove_fields"
    remove_field => [ "@version" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    id => "els_cluster"
    action => "index"
    index => "my_index"
    template_name => "my_index_template"
    hosts => [
      "https://myhost1.com:9200",
      "https://myhost2.com:9200",
      "https://myhost3.com:9200",
      "https://myhost4.com:9200"
    ]
    cacert => '/mycertificate.cer'
    user => "my_user"
    password => "my_password"

I have two nodes of Logstash and 7 millions of data in the database.
If I start my logstash on both nodes (or one) it keeps fetching the data and does not stop.
I use Logstash 8.11.4 version.
Do you have any idea how can I read 7 millions of data with both nodes?

Can you please provide query which you have put in sql file.

As far as I know, it is not possible as of now, and you can refer to this GitHub issue, which has been open for a long time.
What you can do is segregate your data based on some field, like date, category, or any other field, and use that field value in the where clause to define multiple pipelines.
Let's consider you have a category field with values like A, B, and C. Then you can define each pipeline with a where clause in the category field with these values. If you have a date field, then you can create a date range and create one pipeline for each date range.
There is one more suggestion: have a unique ID based on a unique fingerprint, which will make sure that you will not have duplicate data in your index. You can refer to this answer for the same approach.
